# how to read back result when using mongodb transaction?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

All mongodb transaction examples I have seen so far don't allow reading results back. For example (pseudo code):

```
begin_transaction
collection_one.update(...)
collection_two.update(...)
commit_transaction
```

The problem is, what if I want to update collection_two based on the result of updating collection_one?

For example?

```
begin_transaction
result = collection_one.update(...)
if (result.update_count() > 0)
{
    collection_two.update(...)
}
commit_transaction
```

I have never seen an example like the above? It seems that when use transaction, I can't get the result back.

Another example,

```
begin_transaction
result = collection_children.find({name: 'xxx'})
collection_team.delete({name in result})
commit_transaction
```

Basically, I want to perform a find on a collection, and based the find result to perform a second action on a different collection.

And I want the 2 actions together be atomic.

Comment: Your two examples are slightly different. Have you tried this yourself ? if so, could you replace the pseudo code with a snippet (i.e. mongo shell, or any of the drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this works as expected with Mongoose. The same example obviously is possible without Mongoose.

```
var author = new Author({ email: "test22@test.com", other: [{a: 1}});
var book = new Book({ title: 'ABC' })

let doFoo = async () => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  try {
    const opts = { session, new: true };

    let _author = await author.save()  // Notice we get back the record
    let _book = await book.save()

    // Notice we are using now the new id of the just saved record
    await Author.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: _author.id }, { $set: { other: { foo: 2 } }},  opts);
    await Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: _book.id }, { $set: { title: "ABC" }},  opts);

    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    session.endSession();
    throw error; // Rethrow so calling function sees error
  }
}

doFoo()
```

So in the example above we create/save two different records in their respective collections and after that based on the new records we go back and update them.